Can one bound a moment of a random variable with bounded support if given the lower moments?
If $X$ is a random variable whose support is a bounded interval, say, $[0, 1]$, and the 1st through $n$th moments $\mathbb{E}[X] = m_1, \mathbb{E}[X^2] = m_2, \dots, \mathbb{E}[X^n] = m_n$ are known, then what can be said about $(n + 1)$th moment $\mathbb{E}[X^{n + 1}]$? Can any upper or lower bounds for it be determined in terms of the known moments?
In my brief research I've found the Hausdorff moment problem, which provides necessary and sufficient conditions for an infinite sequence $m_1, m_2, \dots$ to be the moments of a random variable with support $[0, 1]$, and if the sequence is valid then it uniquely determines the variable.
In my case, knowing a finite number of moments does not, in general, uniquely determine a random variable, and there may be an infinite family of random variables with support $[0, 1]$ that have first $n$ moments $m_1, \dots, m_n$. I'm interested if there is any general way of determining what are the possible values (minimum, maximum) of the $(n+1)$th moment among the variables in that family, and what kind of distribution achieves these extremums.

Welcome to the site ! For the upper bound at least, Hölder's inequality could be helpful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality

According to the solution of the Hausdorff moment problem,
the sequence of $k$'th differences of the moments (including the $0$'th moment which is $1$ for a probability measure) must be nonnegative if $k$ is even and nonpositive if $k$ is odd.  So e.g. if you know $m_0 = 1$, $m_1 = 3/5$, $m_2 = 2/5$, $m_3 = 2/7$, and $m_4$ is unknown, the first differences are
$$ 3/5 - 1 = -2/5,\ 2/5 - 3/5 = -1/5,\ 2/7 - 2/5 = -4/35, \ m_4 - 2/7, \ldots $$
so $m_4 - 2/7 \le 0$, the second differences are
$$ 1/5, 3/35, m_4 - 6/35, \ldots $$
so $m_4 - 6/35 \ge 0$, the third differences are
$$ -4/35, m_4 - 9/35, \ldots $$
so $m_4 - 9/35 \le 0$, and the first fourth difference is $m_4 - 1/7 \ge 0$.
We conclude that $6/35 \le m_4 \le 9/35$.
Caution: these are necessary conditions, but not sufficient.  You can
get more constraints by considering more unknown moments.
